# SQL DELETE too long when LEFT joining

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have three tables, first is **contact**, containing all contacts with their names, emails etc.
 second one is **cross_contactList_contact**, which is only used as help table to connect each contact to multiple contact-lists.
 third one contains names and settings of contact-lists and its not used in this query.

This query is launched once after the contact list is deleted from its own table and after  all rows in cross table containing that deleted list id are also deleted. This query is then something like "clean-up", it checks if there are any contacts, that are NOT in any other contact-lists.

Problem is, that my DB needs to work with 1 mil. - 2. mil. rows, but for testing purposes, Im using "only" **around 70 000 contacts** in 5 different contact lists (around 80 000 records in cross_contactList_contact, few of the contacts are in multiple list, one of the lists has circa 60 000 records, others < 3 000) **but the query is runinnng around 18-20 minutes in total**!

```
    DELETE contact FROM contact 
    LEFT JOIN cross_contactList_contact ON contact.id = cross_contactList_contact.contact_id
    WHERE cross_contactList_contact.contactList_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Can you try WHERE IN() ,without using a JOIN?

Comment: Check the corresponding `SELECT` query with `EXPLAIN SELECT contact FROM contact 
    LEFT JOIN cross_contactList_contact ON contact.id = cross_contactList_contact.contact_id
    WHERE cross_contactList_contact.contactList_id IS NULL`

Comment: what indexes do you have on `contact` and `cross_contactList_contact`? Can you include those index creation scripts into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was okay after i regenerated indexes, so there was no problem at all. Thanks.